# Prove that there exists $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb R$ is a continuous function such that :

For each $x \in [a,b]$,  there exists $y \in [a,b]$ such that $2|f(y)| \le |f(x)|$  .

Prove that there exists $c \in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)=0$ .

Note : Its like mean value theorem except that here, i don't which values to take such that one of them is greater than zero and the other one is less than zero...

Answer (score 6):

- Build a sequence $(x_n)_{n\geq 0}$ such that $\lvert f(x_n)\rvert \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$. You can do that iteratively thanks to the assumption: set $x_0 \stackrel{\rm def}{=} b$, let $x_1$ be the "corresponding $y\in[a,b]$," and so on. *(Thanks to the assumption, $\lvert f(x_{n+1})\rvert \leq \frac{\lvert f(x_{n})\rvert}{2}$ for all $n\geq 0$.)*
- Extract a converging subsequence $(x'_n)_{n\geq 0}$ from $(x_n)_{n\geq 0}$. You can, because $[a,b]$ is compact.
- What can you say about $f(\ell)$, where $\ell\in[a,b]$ is the limit of the subsequence $(x'_n)_{n\geq 0}$? *(Here, the continuity of $f$ will be helpful.)*

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $f(c)\ne 0,\forall c\in [a,b].$ Since $|f|$ is continous on $[a,b]$ and $[a,b]$ is compact there exists $m\in [a,b]$ such that $$0<|f(m)|\le |f(x)|, \forall x\in [a,b].$$ But then, by hypothesis, there exists $y\in[a,b]$ such that $2|f(y)|\le |f(m)|.$ So $$2|f(m)|\le2|f(y)|\le |f(m)|..$$ Thus it must be $f(m)=0,$ which gives us the desired contradiction.

Comment: i don't know anything about compactness but i know Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem ... does that work ?

Comment: Do you know Weirstrass extreme value theorem? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem Actually is what I have used. Anyway, compact means closed and bounded, in this case.

Comment: i know that theorem ... two things are kind of strange to me ... $|f(m)| \le |f(x)|$ ... why ?  the second thing , why $y \in [a,m] $ not $y \in [a,b]$ ?

Comment: The second is a typo. I am sorry. With respect to the first question the theorem says that $|f|$ attains a minimum, say at $m.$ Thus, $|f(m)|\le |f(x)|,\forall x.$ Note that we are applying the theorem to $|f|$ and not to $f.$