# Let I := [a, b] and let f : I → R be a continuous function on I such that for each x ∈ I there exists y ∈ I such that |f(x)| > 2|f(y)|

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let I := [a, b] and let f : I → R be a continuous function on I such that
for each x ∈ I there exists y ∈ I such that |f(x)| > 2|f(y)|. Prove there exists a point c ∈ I such that
f(c) = 0.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried? Where are you stuck? You need to [provide context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) for your question. Otherwise it just looks like you want somebody to do your homework for you; that's not what this site is for. If you add some appropriate context, we will be happy to help.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037571/prove-that-there-exists-c-in-a-b-such-that-fc-0?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: take $x_0\in I$, $x_1: |f(x_0)|>2|f(x_1)|$, suppose defined $x_n$, take $x_{n+1}:|f(x_n)|>2|f(x_{n+1})|$, since $I$ is compact, you can extract a subsequence $x_{n_p}$ which converges towards $x$, show tha $f(x)=0$.